# jq: Lifting fields from array of objects into the parent object

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON object an array at the top-level, and each array entry is an object with a nested array of objects as one of the fields.
I'd like to "lift" some fields from the sub-arrays into the objects within the first array. It's confusing to write, so, here's my input:

```
{ "emails": [
  { "email":"foo1@bar.com",
    "events":[
      { "type":"open", "time":"t1", "ignore":"this" },
      { "type":"click", "time":"t2", "ignore":"this" } ] },
  { "email":"foo2@bar.com",
    "events":[
      { "type":"open", "time":"t3", "ignore":"this" },
      { "type":"click", "time":"t4", "ignore":"this" },
      { "type":"open", "time":"t5", "ignore":"this" } ] }
] }
```

What I'd like to receive as output is:

```
[
  { "email":"foo1@bar.com", "type":"open", "time":"t1" },
  { "email":"foo1@bar.com", "type":"click", "time":"t2" },
  { "email":"foo2@bar.com", "type":"open", "time":"t3" },
  { "email":"foo2@bar.com", "type":"click", "time":"t4" },
  { "email":"foo2@bar.com", "type":"open", "time":"t5" }
]
```

I can `jq` this with multiple pipes already, like so:

```
 [ .emails[] | { email:.email, event:(.events[] | { type:.type, time:.time }) } | { email:.email, type:.event.type, time:.event.time } ]
```

... but this seems way too verbose.
Is there an easier way to 'lift' those `type` and `time` fields from the deepest objects to the object one-level up?
When I try to use the `.events[]` iterator twice, I wind up with the Cartesian product of events, which is wrong :-/

I must be missing some simpler way (than my 'intermediate-object' approach above) to achieve this ... anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Let's proceed in two steps: first, the (heavy) lifting, and secondly, the (light) trimming.

#### Lifting

```
.emails | map( {email}  + .events[])
```

or equivalently:

```
[.emails[] | {email}  + .events[]]
```

Notice that `{"email": .email}` has been abbreviated to `{email}`.

#### Trimming

We can delete the "ignore" key using `del(.ignore)`. With an eye to efficiency, we arrive at the following solution:

```
.emails | map( {email}  + (.events[] | del(.ignore) ) )
```

Comment: you forgot a parenthesis the real answer is: `.emails | map( {email}  + (.events[] | del(.ignore)))`

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @peak Another example of the same idea that confused me: `+` looks like a two-operand operator, but the implicit `map` over the multiple values of `.events[]` is super-nice. Super-helpful and super-appreciated.

Comment: Applying the idea that @peak so kindly taught me, my proposed solution is `[ .emails[] | { email } + ( .events[] | del(.ignore) ) ]`.